# Typecheck deeply nested props in React, with Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

It's common for us to have deeply nested components with props passed from the top down via object spread:

```
render() {
  return <MyComponent { ...this.props } />;
}
```

In many cases, components in the middle are not aware of the props flowing through them this way, and to annotate every prop flowing through every component would require that these compositional components know everything about every child.

Is there a way to avoid this, such that props annotated at the top of the hierarchy will be checked against their usage in the bottom of the hierarchy, without needing to annotate inside every component between, and without simply exporting and importing type aliases, which would break the hierarchical relationship?

Comment: Flow requires exports of modules be annotated explicitly (http://flowtype.org/docs/modules.html#missing-required-annotations). I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Flow's [typeof operator](http://flowtype.org/docs/typeof.html) by declaring `ParentComponent.someProp` to have the same type as `ChildComponent.someOtherProp`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do that without 1) requiring that the parent or child know specifically about the other, or 2) exporting and importing type aliases. Could you maybe include some sample code to illustrate your idea?

Comment: You won't get past #1 with Flow's type checking. You could use `any` type, but that would disable type checking. Consider composing your components differently such that instead of passing unknown child's props you pass an element with those props already applied. I understand that this is not what you want, but it might help in some limited cases.